# C6386: Переполнение буфера при записи

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, методы, переполнение

Реализую свой класс для работы с матрицами, но в одном из методов класса при анализе кода Visual Studio сообщает о переполнении буфера.

Код:

```
typedef unsigned int UINT;

class NumCxx
{
   //some implementation
};


UINT NumCxx::ones(UINT columns, UINT rows) // Method ones creates the matrix;
// UINT - unsigned int
{
    if (!checkout())
    {
        this->dim_array_ = new int* [columns_]; // Creates an array
    }

    this->columns_ = columns;
    this->rows_ = rows;
    this->length_ = columns_; // length of an array

    for (UINT i = 0; i < columns_; ++i)
    {
        dim_array_[i] = new int[rows_]; // PROBLEM is here

        for (UINT j = 0; j < rows_; ++j)
        {
           dim_array_[i][j] = 1;
        }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio подсвечивает строку `dim_array_[i] = new int[rows_];` и говорит о переполнении буфера.

Метод `UINT NumCxx::checkout()` проверяет, создавалась ли матрица и если нет, то строка `this->dim_array_ = new int* [columns_];` создает двумерный динамический массив.

Код checkout():

```
  UINT NumCxx::checkout()
  {
    if (length_) // Если длина была задана (по умолчанию в конструкторе = 0)
    {
        for (UINT i = 0; i < length_; ++i)
        {
            delete[] dim_array_[i];
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Как устранить этот неприятный момент, или же просто проигнорировать (не хотелось бы) ?

Comment: А вы не пробовали написать не `dim_array_`, а `this->dim_array_`?

Comment: @Harry Ничего не поменялось, по прежнему подчеркивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Абсолютно не понятно зачем нужен вам член  `length_` , когда у вас
   есть и количество строк и количество столбцов.
2. Не обращаем на это внимание и допускаем, что до вызова `checkout` 
   `length_ != 0`. Тогда функцией `checkout` освобождается  память,
   количеством  `length_`(непонятно сколько), и затем в функции `ones`
   присваивается указательям (но теперь указатели другого количества)
   значение.

Может все таки хотели  `this->dim_array_ = new int* [rows_]  и  dim_array_[i] = new int[columns_];`???

P.S. вместо `length_`(это поле вам больше мешает мне кажется) просто используйте  `columns_`